# Subquery in FROM clause only returns one row in outer SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT *,
       MAX((curbalance + ABS(maxneg)) >= 2.00
           OR FIND_IN_SET('bookkeeper', rights)) AS eligible
FROM
  ( SELECT players.*,
           MAX(drawing = '2014-05-10') AS in_drawing,
           SUM(amount) AS curbalance
   FROM players
   LEFT JOIN transactions ON playerid = employeeid
   GROUP BY COALESCE(nickname, FIRST),
            LAST ) foo
```

Which should return 20+ rows, but for the life of me only returns a single row. When I use EXPLAIN I notice that the primary and derived tables have 23 rows, but the result set only has one row.

Am I missing something obvious? I can provide details on my table layout if that would help.

Comment: Your outer query has an aggregation function (`max()`) but no `group by`.  It will return only one row.

Comment: Ugh... thank you. I don't know how I missed that, I want the last few hours of my life back. =)